# Remove border RadioButton?

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

Can I remove border of `RadioButton` and I have `RadioButtons` like bellow :

[image]

I see a lot of question and I used from `android:buttonTint=""` and `style` ... but don't work .

Comment: can you explain the problem?

Comment: This is radioButton :https://stackoverflow.com/q/33260009/4813855

Comment: You're asking about RadioButtons. But you are showing what looks like a ViewPager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a custom radio button to change the style in that way. Read this [article](https://crosp.net/blog/android/creating-custom-radio-groups-radio-buttons-android/) if you want to learn how to do it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove that using the radiobutton.
what you can do is set it to the same color as your background, 
or create a custom radiobutton XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_checked="false" 
android:drawable="@drawable/your_radio_off_image_name" />
<item android:state_checked="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/your_radio_on_image_name" />
</selector>
```

use that XML in your layout:

```
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radiobutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:button="@drawable/custom_radiobutton"/>
```

more info and examples about custom xml:
[Adding custom radio buttons in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android)

[remove default radio button checkbox when using a custom selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297991/remove-default-radio-button-checkbox-when-using-a-custom-selector)

Another option is to use a toggle instead of radiobutton, and just change the drawable onToggle.

Comment: is this thing working?I am trying to implement it and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't remove this.You can custom radio button.